# How to show a 360 video in VR using Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm looking to create an app in Unity 2021.3 (LTS) for Android/iOS that will show a 360 video (it's an mp4, still from the video below) and for the user to be able to look around it with a VR headset (Google Cardboard at this point).

I picked the above Unity version as it has LTS, and eventually I'd go on to turn this into a project that may need maintaining long term, but open to other versions if this one is a barrier.

I haven't developed with Unity for about 4-5 years, but I have no experience at all with using it with videos or VR.

One example I found of someone else wanting to do similar to me, was [on the Unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/vr-360-video-on-android-mobile-how.1369776/) where in the answers it was suggested OP use a modern version of Unity and Google Cardboard, which I have, but there was no solution at the end putting these things together to play a video you can look around.

I did follow the [Google cardboard Unity quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart) to get that set up, and ran the sample which allowed me to look around a 3D scene, but not sure how much help that is to me when it's a video I'm wanting to look around, and whether I still needed to have it set up.

I followed [this article about using a sphere](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-make-a-360-vr-app-with-unity-51cbe41ad8f1), but it was apparent it was quite old, not only using a 6 year old version of Unity, but a since archived GoogleVR SDK. The end result was no movement and the video looked like a stretched out regular video.

I also followed [this Unity guide using a skybox and render texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VideoPanoramic.html), but although it's labelled as a 2021.3 article, some of the settings (like depth buffer) don't exist, so not sure if this was based on an older version. The end result was similar to the above one, no movement and the video looked like a stretched out regular video. I did somehow get this one to a point where the video on my Android appeared to be showing 2 split videos, one looking like my video displayed vertically on the left of the screen, and on the right of the screen a stretched video horizontal video.

Does anyone know of any modern guides that can get me started with an app to play my 360 video on Google cardboard, or any generic VR headset for that matter that uses a phone for the display, where I can look around the video as it plays? Or if no guides, just some steps on what to do.

A still from the sample video showing the kind of 360 video I have.

[image: Example 360 video]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Cody C's answer, I decided I would start fresh.

I followed the [Google Cardboard SDK quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart), and ran the sample so I knew it was working.

I then created a new scene and [followed the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HwX02YuFtk) from the guide I [previously linked](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-make-a-360-vr-app-with-unity-51cbe41ad8f1) to create a sphere and apply the texture etc for the video.

At 6mins 30secs into the video, I stopped watching as it moved onto the old GoogleVR SDK setup, which is no longer needed now I'm using the carboard sdk.

I deleted the Main Camera from my scene, and then copied the Player and its child Camera GameObject from the HelloCardboard scene into my scene, ran it on my android device and that's it. I could then look around the 360 video.

I did have to set the X scale on the sphere to -50, otherwise the video was appearing horizontally flipped (backwards text etc. in video etc)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've been quite close to the answer!

Where you got with the one tutorial (where you could look around a 3D scene), that was pretty much all the work done. To create a video that you can look around, simply create a 3D sphere in Unity and apply the video to the texture You will then have a video sphere which you can look around in!

There are plenty of tutorials on YouTube that can get you up and running with the Google Cardboard SDK. I think anything from 2021 onwards would be safe to use and not much would have changed since then. As for your Unity version, it would be safe to use a newer version of Unity, 2021 isn't needed specifically.

One you have a scene running which lets you look around in 3D space, just add the video sphere like I mentioned and that should be it. You'll want to make sure to be using the most recent version of the Google Cardboard SDK, obviously:
https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart

^Following this quick start guide will most likely be the best resource, compared to any unofficial YouTube videos

Let me know if you have any questions or if you need further clarification ect

Comment: Thanks for this! It became quite clear I just needed to start again with the cardboard sdk and go from there. I posted an answer with the steps I took, but this helped me get there. Thank you